# How to get Longitude and Latitude from Google Map URL

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, google-maps

I want to extract longitude and Latitude from Google Map URL
Is this possible to use Jquery to extract them
Like

> `https://www.google.com/maps/place/Arctic+Pixel+Digital+Solutions/@63.6741553,-164.9587713,4z/data=!3m1!4b1!4m5!3m4!1s0x5133b2ed09c706b9:0x66deacb5f48c5d57!8m2!3d64.751111!4d-147.3494442`

The Longitude and latitude are 
Logitude : 63.6741553
Latitude : -164.9587713

I want to extract them with jquery

Comment: use split in javascript http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_split.asp

Comment: @prakashtank Can you please help me to use it ?

Comment: Why not use the API instead of hacking around a URL string?

Comment: @hammad, as prakash tank said below I put the ready code for you with javascript split().

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
var url = "https://www.google.com/maps/place/Arctic+Pixel+Digital+Solutions/@63.6741553,-164.9587713,4z/data=!3m1!4b1!4m5!3m4!1s0x5133b2ed09c706b9:0x66deacb5f48c5d57!8m2!3d64.751111!4d-147.3494442";
var regex = new RegExp('@(.*),(.*),');
var lat_long_match = url.match(regex);
var lat = lat_long_match[1];
var long = lat_long_match[2];
```

Based on the comment, I assume this is exactly what you're looking for:

```
<script>
    $(function() {
        $('#btn').on('click', function() {
            var url = $('input[name=googlemapurl]').val();
            var regex = new RegExp('@(.*),(.*),');
            var lat_long_match = url.match(regex);
            var lat = lat_long_match[1];
            var long = lat_long_match[2];

            $('input[name=latitude]').val(lat);
            $('input[name=longitude]').val(long);
        });
    });
</script>

<p><input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Google Map Link" name="googlemapurl"/></p>
<p><input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="GPS Latitude" name="latitude" /></p>
<p><input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="GPS Longitude" name="longitude" /></p>
<p><button id="btn">Extract</button></p>
```

Comment: how to use with autoget url

Comment: ' <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="GPS Longitude" name="longitude" />
<input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="GPS Latitude" name="latitude" />
<input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Google Map Link" name="googlemapurl"/>'

Comment: You mean you pass URL to `googlemapurl` input field and when you click button, you will get longitude and latitude values in the those corresponding input fields. Right?

Comment: Yup Exactly i need this

Comment: I've updated my answer. You can check it out.

Comment: Sir its not working

Comment: You have any other code in your HTML file? I just posted you the sample code. So, you need to change it according to your actual code you have.

Comment: Yup I have a huge form too

Comment: I'm not sure the way you have your code. Otherwise, give me some hints how you've written your code.

Comment: Just a Bootstrap form

Comment: let me add your code in new page

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/j0tgLv8u/ Check this

Comment: You have pasted JS code in CSS section. Also, you need not to use `<script>` explicitly in `jsfiddle`.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/j0tgLv8u/1/ Still not working

Comment: Remove `<script>` tag in `jsfiddle`.

Comment: I already Did Sir

Comment: I got it. You need to specify `jquery` CDN in `jsfiddle`. Click `External Resources` on the left side pane. Paste `https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js` in the input field and click `+` button beside it to add the CDN to its resources list and that's it.

Comment: Had you tried ? because its not working

Comment: Yeah. I tried it adding `jquery` in it and it worked.

Comment: Here the URL is https://jsfiddle.net/j0tgLv8u/3/.

Comment: You need to add `jquery` in `jsfiddle` in order for the code to work since it is written with `jQuery`.

Comment: That's nice. Glad about it. :)

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```js
var URL =  "https://www.google.com/maps/place/Arctic+Pixel+Digital+Solutions/@63.6741553,-164.9587713,4z/data=!3m1!4b1!4m5!3m4!1s0x5133b2ed09c706b9:0x66deacb5f48c5d57!8m2!3d64.751111!4d-147.3494442";

var splitUrl = URL.split('!3d');
var latLong = splitUrl[splitUrl.length-1].split('!4d');
var longitude;

if (latLong.indexOf('?') !== -1) {
    longitude = latLong[1].split('\\?')[0];
} else {
    longitude = latLong[1];
}
var latitude = latLong[0];

console.log(latitude); //64.751111
console.log(longitude); //-147.3494442
```

I'm grabbing the "!3d" and "!4d" Latitude and Longitude at the end of the URL because they are more accurate than the ones after the "@".

Take this url as an example (GooglePlex):
https://www.google.com/maps/place/Googleplex/@37.4219999,-122.0862462,17z/data=!3m1!4b1!4m5!3m4!1s0x808fba02425dad8f:0x6c296c66619367e0!8m2!3d37.4219999!4d-122.0840575

The latitude and longitude after the "@" are:
Lat: (37.4219999)
Long: (-122.0862462)
And they aren't accurate.

However, the ones at the end of the URL are:
Lat: (37.4219999)
Long: (-122.0840575)
Those are accurate.

Answer (score 0):

check out this link, you can find how to extract longitude and Latitude from Google Map URL

https://github.com/wimagguc/jquery-latitude-longitude-picker-gmaps/blob/master/demo.html

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Answer (score 0):

```
var url="https://www.google.com/maps/place/Arctic+Pixel+Digital+Solutions/@63.6741553,-164.9587713,4z/data=!3m1!4b1!4m5!3m4!1s0x5133b2ed09c706b9:0x66deacb5f48c5d57!8m2!3d64.751111!4d-147.3494442";

var longlat = /\/\@(.*),(.*),/.exec(url);

var lat = longlat[1]; //63.6741553
var lng = longlat[2]; //-164.9587713
```

[Live example](https://jsfiddle.net/nd4qxc3c/)

EDIT:

[Example with inputs](https://jsfiddle.net/nd4qxc3c/1/)

Comment: Thanks But I am not that much professional in Javascript can you please help me how to show this in input field?

Comment: sure, check out my edit (`example with inputs` link)

Comment: Thanks alot man. Is this possible to autoget url from input field? 
like a input field with Google map url .

Comment: Autoget URL? Can you elaborate it?

Comment: <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="GPS Longitude" name="longitude" />
<input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="GPS Latitude" name="latitude" />
<input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Google Map Link"  name="googlemapurl"/>

Comment: Can you please help ?

Comment: I'm not sure what are you asking for... but generally Google Maps API creates `IFrame` and you can't access the inputs in there as cross domain policy of browser won't allow it.

Comment: I just want to enter url in input field and OnMouseOver I want it to set on var url

Comment: EDIT: The first param here is the lat and second param is the long.

var lat = longlat[1]; //63.6741553
var lng = longlat[2]; //-164.9587713